# QML: SequencialAnimation's running attribute set to false, but still running

Tags: javascript, qt, animation, qml

i made animations in transition. so if state change, so the transition is emitted. here is the sequential animation that i made.

```
SequentialAnimation{
            PropertyAnimation{
                properties: "width"
                duration: 300
            }
            PropertyAnimation{
                properties: "x"
                duration: 500
            }
            Component.onCompleted: {
                var idx = Math.ceil(Math.random()*2);
                if(idx===0){
                    anim0.running = true
                    anim1.running = false
                }
                else {
                    anim1.running = true
                    anim0.running = false
                }
                console.log("haha");
            }
        }

        SequentialAnimation{
            id: anim0
            running: false
            NumberAnimation{
                running: anim0.running
                properties: "x"
                to: 300
                duration: 500
            }
            Component.onCompleted: console.log("anim0");
        }
        SequentialAnimation{
            id: anim1
            running: false
            NumberAnimation{
                running: anim1.running
                properties: "x"
                to: -300
                duration: 500
            }
            Component.onCompleted: console.log("anim1");
        }
```

Ignore the JavaScript first on Component.onCompleted signal.
SequencialAnimation with id: anim1 and anim0 keep running although i had already set running attribute to false...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `running` property of an `Animation` item to false, will not prevent the animation start. It will just stop it if it's currently runnging.

If you don't want an animation to be started in a transition, then just don't put it inside a transition.
You can always define your custom `Animation` Item outside the `Transition`, and trigger it when you want to by using the `animationId.start()` function.

For detailed informations see the [documentation page](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qml-animation.html#running-prop).

Comment: Hai.. thx for your help..but, how to do it? do i have to call it in the sequentialAnimation? or using signal? i'm very new about qml..

Comment: Well, this depends on what you want to do... In which case you were setting the `running` property to true?